# rdesktop on unix

Tags: remote-desktop

Does anybody know if it's possible to disable error messages, such as invalid password, in the rdesktop client on unix? I'd like to write a script that uses rdesktop in a while loop, but it seems to hang if I don't auth properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. It's not possible. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: You gave up about 39 seconds too soon.

Answer (score 1):

Why not test the username and password against the server first, using something else (SMB perhaps)?

Comment: An excellent suggestion. However, some of these systems live inside the DMZ and I can only see port 3389 on them.

Answer (score 0):

Something is afoot! Why would you want to repeatedly login to a remote desktop session with an invalid password?

I'll bite ...

```
rdesktop 2> /dev/null
```

Just a simple error redirection should work. But still. Why do you need to write a while loop for an interactive process?

Comment: rdesktop 2> /dev/null will redirect errors from the client itself but not errors presented from the GINA. Most of the machines in my survey have the same account, but not all. That's a fine situation, but I want to have the while loop continue when it gets a failure from the outliers.

Really though, there's no way to do this without hacking the rdesktop source. My plan is to try sending 'enter' on detection.

Comment: Ah. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume you did what I did, took a Pos desktop, put rdesktop on it and secured it down.  On boot mine executes rdesktop to our terminal service.

Two options
1) create a link on desktop to recreate connection(easy fast cheap)
2) create a script that waits for rdesktop to exit, on return it restarts rdesktop.
This is very doable but a pain in the ass.  you'll need to learn signal handlers for this.